# Issues with whitespace around SVG in IE11, related to text in the SVG

Tags: html, svg, internet-explorer-11

I'm having issues with large amounts of whitespace surrounding an SVG in internet explorer. I've created the simplest example I could that reproduces the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<svg width="600" height="600" viewbox="0 0 600 600">
  <rect fill="powderblue" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600"/>
  <text x="500" y="500">test</text>
</svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Viewing this in IE11 produces a large amount whitespace to the right and below the SVG. Note the scrollbars in the screenshot below, indicating the large amount of empty space in IE but not in Chrome.
[image: Screenshot with Chrome on the left and IE on the right]

The whitespace disappears if I do any of the following:

- Remove the viewbox attribute
- Move the text further to the top right
- Delete the text (don't have to delete the text tags, just the content)

As an experiment I added a paragraph below the SVG to see if the whitespace would displace the paragraph. The paragraph appeared directly below the SVG - it wasn't displaced by the whitespace.

Any idea how I can fix this so that the whitespace doesn't appear?

Comment: IE 11 displays just what any other browser would: a 600px by 600px powderblue square with a text positioned at 500px/500px. No special issue there. What do you *want* to achieve, exactly?

Comment: It's not clear what you think is going wrong.  Removing the `viewbox` (which should be `viewBox` BTW) does not change anything here.  Perhaps post a screenshot that shows what you think is going wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce the effect with IE 11.187.14393 on Windows 10 Pro Version 1607. On the other hand, the browser wouldn't show the SVG at all unless I stated the svg namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 at work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obviously a bug in IE.  One simple workaround is to set `overflow: hidden` on the SVG.

```css
svg {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="600" viewbox="0 0 600 600">
  <rect fill="powderblue" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600"/>
  <text x="500" y="500">test</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is the whitespace around the left and top of the svg box, try setting the body margin to 0

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```